# Rails 3.1 custom controller action keeps asking for ID even when route is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, controller, routes

I'm trying to add a custom action ('last_five') to a controller.

My routes are specified as:

```
people_last_five GET  /people/last_five(.:format)  {:action=>"last_five", :controller=>"people"}
```

(i.e. that's the output of rake_routes).

But when I browse to /people/last_five I get the following error.

> Started GET "/people/last_five" for XXX.XX.XXX.XXX at Sun May 15 22:03:18 +0000 2011
>     Processing by PeopleController#last_five as HTML
>     User Load (1.4ms)^[[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
>   Completed   in 86ms
>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Person without an ID):

I thought this was a problem in my routes.rb

In my routes.rb I currently have:

```
get 'people/last_five'
resources :people
```

I've also tried

```
resources :people do
  get 'last_five', :on => collection
end
```

but that gives the same results.

Why is rails trying to get an ID when there is no "/:id/" in the route?

This even happens when I specify the route as '/people/:id/last_five' and pass it a dummy id. In that case it still tells me ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Person without an ID).

I have this problem even when I reduce the action itself to a stub for debugging, so I don't think that's the problem. In my controller:

```
  # GET /people/last_five                                                                                                                                                 
def last_five
  logger.info "LAST FIVE IS BEING CALLED"
  #@people = Person.last_five
  #respond_with @people do |format|
  #   format.json { render :json => @people }
  #end
end
```

Any idea what's going on here? It seems like rails is being told to get an ID by something outside of routes.rb. I've looked everywhere I can think.

Any leads are HIGHLY appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:
My PeopleController begins like so:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => []
filter_resource_access
respond_to :html, :js, :json
```

Comment: Any chance your `People` controller has a before filter in it to look up a user?

Comment: Thanks for your comment dmarkow. Yes. I'm using devise. Have edited above to show filters. Would this make a difference? It's asking for a Person ID. I'm still somewhat new at this though.

Comment: I'd guess it's your filter_resource_access. try commenting that out and see if it works.

Comment: Dmarkow, thanks! It looks like this might be the solution. If I turn off the before filters it works fine (though of course I'll need to keep some sort of authentication). What's going on here? Why would that have an effect? I'll dig around a bit in Devise.

Comment: John Gibb, yes it is. Thanks. Do you know what's going on? Does filter_resource_access interfere with routes?

Comment: Thanks for your comments John and Dmarkow. Replacing filter_resource_access with filter_access_to :all fixes the problem. I will write up a little explanation to help others who might read this. If you guys repeat your answers as answers I can accept them (still new to StackOverflow so not sure if I can upvote them but will do if possible). I've been at this for a while and you guys helped big time. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the discussion on your questions, the cause is a before/around filter interfering rather than an issue with your specific action. Your application is searching for a `User`, so it may be authentication-related.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this goes in Control, and not in Model? Rails doesn't want Model stuff in Control.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it goes in the Control. This is routing information to the user. As I understand MVC this is the role of the controller. I'm happy to be corrected if anyone can explain why this should not go in controller.